# Installing Ubuntu onto an external HDD without a USB or CD?

Tags: boot, usb

I don't have a spare USB stick or optical drive, and am hoping I can install Ubuntu onto an external SSD without either of those things somehow. I've tried using both Rufus and UNetbootin, but both of these programs only create the trial version of the OS; it doesn't seem that they can either install the full operating system or set-up for a full install after booting from the external SSD.

I don't suppose anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: You could clarify your question. You mix HDD and SSD between title and question. What is the trial version of ubuntu ? You mean the Live USB/CD session ? You need to "burn"  ISO onto an USB key or CD to boot from it, then install ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The *blocking thing* is the fact that you don't have/want to use an *USB key or CD*.

Because after having booted the Live USB/CD, you just install on the external SSD as normal.

You **can** boot an ISO from grub. So if your bootloader is *GRUB 2*, you can use the **loopback feature** to boot an ubuntu ISO.

First, you need the UUID of the filesystem where is the iso. Use `sudo blkid` output for that.

Then, you add at the end of  `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
insmod search_fs_uuid
insmod ntfs
search --no-floppy --set=isopart --fs-uuid xxxxxxxxx
set imgdevpath="/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxxxxx"

menuentry '[loopback]ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64' {
    set isofile='/path/to/iso/ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso'
    loopback loop ($isopart)$isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile locale=en_US.UTF-8 noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

You have to replace `xxxxxxx` with the correct UUID.

You need to change `/path/to/iso` with the path to the iso minus the mount point.
Say the fs is mounted at `/mnt/foo` and the full path is `/mnt/foo/bar/ubuntu.iso`, then you replace `/path/to/iso` with `/bar`.

Then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then you reboot, and choose *[loopback]ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64* in grub menu, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you try partitioning it. I'm not sure if it will work, but you could try to make a ~4GB partition, write the installer there, and then attempt to use it to write to the rest of the disk. Alternatively, you could shrink an (assumingly Windows) drive's main partition down ~4GB, install the installer there, and boot from that partition to install to the external HDD (removing the partition from C: after used).

You can use Disk Management if you do the C: drive partition method (Win+X and then Disk Management) - right click on the primary C: partition and select shrink, shrink it about 4096 MB.

I can't guarantee any of these will work, as I've never had such constraints to work with.